# Entity Framework database not working (Code First, Web Deploy)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using Asp.Net MVC4 with Entity Framework Code First.

Everything works locally, but when I publish, pages without database access work (on the internet), and any page with it, loads for an age, then gives me a server error.

I have enabled migrations, I have made an InitialCreate migration that is using the current model. I have ran the "Update-Database" command without error.

Any ideas ?

EDIT, thanks to the comment below, here is some detailed information on the error.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Error in stack trace...

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5064458
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,
>   SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity) +341

Also I'm using .sdf database's. Connection strings here...

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Data.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
<add name="ZDataContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|ZData.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

I repeat, it all works locally.

Just uploaded all files manually, got this error...

> Access to the database file is not allowed. [ 1884,File name = d:\virtualservers[username]\website.co.uk\wwwroot\App_Data\ZData.sdf,SeCreateFile ]

Again that works locally, and also works on none database pages, but databases pages give me the above error.

Comment: In case you don't know it: You can display errors and stack trace by setting `<customErrors mode="Off" />` in `<system.web>` section in your `web.config` file (should be used only temporarily for error tracing). This could help to get a better error description than "*gives me a server error*".

Comment: Is there SQL Server CE installed on the target environment?

Comment: It should be, as I used a .sdf database previously on the same environment using Asp.Net Web Pages.

Comment: Did you check permissions on the database in the published environment?

Comment: Don't have access to much with database's I'm afraid.

I don't understand, if I upload it, in a locally running state, moving every file to the host, using .sdf databases it should work right ?

Does this mean it **should** be something to do with the environment ?

Comment: Asked the hosts for help, even linked them here for details, they fixed it, was a permissions thing on the environment. Thing is when I use vs2012 web publish again, the permissions go wrong again, why is that !? Quite Annoying.